# Prove that $\prod_{i\in I}X_i\cap\prod_{i\in I}Y_i=\prod_{i\in I}(X_i\cap Y_i)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, set-theory, infinite-product

So if $X$ and $Y$ are two set then any binary relation between $X$ and $Y$ is a subset of the power set $\mathcal P\big(\mathcal P(X\cup Y)\big)$ of $\mathcal P(X\cup Y)$ so that we can define the set $Y^X$ of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ through the equation
$$
Y^X:=\{f\in\mathcal P\big(\mathcal P(X\cup Y)\big):f\,\text{ function}\}
$$

So if $\mathfrak X:=\{X_i:i\in I\}$ is an indexed colletion of sets then we can define too the general caresian product $\prod_{i\in I} X_i$ of $\mathfrak X$ through the equation
$$
\prod_{i\in I}X_i:=\Biggl\{x\in\biggl(\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\biggl)^I:x(i)\in X_i\,\forall i\in I\Biggl\}
$$

Therefore let be now $\mathfrak X:=\{X_i:i\in I\}$ and $\mathfrak Y:=\{Y_i:i\in I\}$ two indexed collections of sets: so I ask to prove that
$$
\prod_{i\in I}X_i\cap\prod_{i\in I}Y_i=\prod_{i\in I}(X_i\cap Y_i)
$$

---

---

$$
\underline{\text{MY PROOF ATTEMPT}}
$$

So first of all we observe that
$$
\prod_{i\in I}X_i\cap\prod_{i\in I}Y_i=\Biggl\{x\in\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\biggr)^I:x(i)\in X_i\,\forall i\in I\Biggl\}\cap\Biggl\{x\in\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}Y_i\biggr)^I:x(i)\in Y_i\,\forall i\in I\Biggl\}=\\
\Biggl\{x\in\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\biggr)^I\cap\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}Y_i\biggr)^I:x(i)\in (X_i\cap Y_i)\,\forall i\in i\Biggl\}
$$
so that the equality follows proving that
$$
\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\biggr)^I\cap\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}Y_i\biggr)^I=\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}(X_i\cap Y_i)\biggr)^I
$$

So on this purpose we observe that if $x$ is an elemento of $\big(\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i\big)^I\cap\big(\bigcup_{i\in I}Y_i\big)^I$ then $x$ is an element of both $\big(\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i\big)^I$ and $\big(\bigcup_{i\in I}Y_i\big)^I$ and thus
$$
\operatorname{ran}x\subseteq\Biggl(\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\cap\bigcup_{i\in I}Y_i\Biggl)=\bigcup_{i\in I}(X_i\cap Y_i)
$$
which impplies that
$$
x\subseteq\operatorname{dom}x\times\operatorname{ran}x\subseteq I\times\bigcup_{i\in I}(X_i\cap Y_i)
$$
so that being $x$ a function we conclude that $x$ is an element of $\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}(X_i\cap Y_i)\biggr)^I$ and this proves that
$$
\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\biggr)^I\cap\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}Y_i\biggr)^I\subseteq\biggr(\bigcup_{I\in I}(X_i\cap Y_i)\biggr)^I
$$

Conversely if $x$ is an element of $\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}(X_i\cap Y_i)\biggr)^I$ then necessarly
$$
\operatorname{ran}x\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}(X_i\cap Y_i)=\Biggl(\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\cap\bigcup_{i\in I}Y_i\Biggl)
$$
and thus
$$
x\subseteq\operatorname{dom}x\times\operatorname{ran}x\subseteq I\times\Biggl(\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\cap\bigcup_{i\in I}Y_i\Biggl)=\Biggl(I\times\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\Biggl)\cap\Biggl(I\times\bigcup_{i\in I}Y_i\Biggl)
$$
so that being $x$ a function necessarly $x$ is an element of both $\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\biggr)^I$ and $\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}Y_i\biggr)^I$ and this proves that
$$
\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}(X_i\cap Y_i)\biggr)^I\subseteq\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\biggr)^I\cap\biggr(\bigcup_{i\in I}Y_i\biggr)^I
$$

---

---

Therefore first of all I would like to know if the argumentation I gave to prove the statement are correct (I think it is very important to learn by your mistakes) and then I do not dislike to know if it is possible to prove it with other argumentations. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: A binary relation between $X$ and $Y$ is a subset of $X \times Y$. If $(x,y)$ is defined to mean $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$, then a binary relation between $X$ and $Y$ would be a subset of $P(P(X \cup Y))$, not of $P(X \cup Y)$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Oh yhea, you are right: so I have to change my proof? is it incorrect?

Comment: In writing down each set in "explicit details", you have made your proof nearly unreadable. What's wrong $f\in\prod X_i\cap\prod Y_i\iff f$ is a function with domain $I$ and $f(i)\in X_i$ as well as $f(i)\in Y_i$ for all $i\in I\iff f$ is a function with domain $I$ and $f(i)\in X_i\cap Y_i$ for all $i\in I\iff f\in\prod(X_i\cap Y_i)$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, for bad notation. So writing the first equality I exactly wanted say, as it seems you said too, that a fuction $f$ is an element of $\prod X_i\cap\prod Y_i$ if and only  the domain of $$ is the index set $I$, the range of $f$ is contained in $(\bigcup\mathfrak X)\cup(\bigcup\mathfrak Y)$ and $f(i)\in X_i\cap Y_i$ for each $i\in I$. That's wrong?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Anyway my biggest concern is the about the truth of the equality $$\biggr(\bigcup X_i\biggr)^I=\biggr(\bigcup Y_i\biggr)^I$$ whose subsistence it seemed to me formally important to prove the statement, that's all. Forgive my confusion; forgive my bad English too.

Comment: It's not your confusion or your English that is the problem. Overformalism is the problem, and if I had to guess, I'd also say that it is one of the drivers of your confusion.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Okay, I accept what you claim since I know that the **over**formalism complicate a lot my life but unfortunately as yet I was not able to do without it: indeed the formalism give me  safety and calmness that the all is right so that I am a bit obsessioned by it, although I realise this is can be counterproductive;

Comment: however for long time I did not understand Mathematics because my old theachers thaught it as a pratical subject and, really I do not why, when I discovered subjects as Set Theory or Topology then all was more clear but unfortunately, being autodidact, I  always fear to make a mistake when I give by myself a proof and in particular I fear to very sloppy, that's all

Comment: In fact, know that unfortunately some nights I do not sleep well because I am worried to do the (mathematical) things badly, that is not (good) formally: I repeat that this is a problem but without a student fellow to study it is some complicated because I cannot discuss my ideas and so I cannot know if they are correct and this is exactly the reason which motivated me to sign to this site. Here I learned much things, really, but unfortunately, I cannot ask if **ALL** my explanations are correct and this a bit torment me because, I repete, I really fear to be sloppy. So forgive my obsession.

Comment: Formalism is a crutch. Training wheels. If you are trying to learn mathematics as a subject, eventually those need to come off.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Okay, so if the formalism is a crutch where now I got wrong? If I exaggerated how many less formal I had to be? pheraps I could give a more simple proof? could you indicate it? I would like to know this because, as I yet stated in the question, I think it is very important to learn by your mistakes. Sorry, for the bother.